Vite HMR abruptly stopped working (React, Vite, Tailwind)
Abruptly, vite's HMR stopped working. I don't think I changed anything significant, I was editing a component and then HMR suddenly froze. When I save a file in VSCode, Vite seems to detect it in the terminal but no change in the webpage (google chrome).
vite.config.js:
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import tailwindcss from "tailwindcss";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  css: {
    postcss: {
      plugins: [tailwindcss()],
    },
  },
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    watch: {
      usePolling: true,
    },
  },
});

tailwind.config.js:
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"], // make sure this is src!!
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}

postcss.config.js:
export default {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}

package.json:
{
  "name": "root",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite && tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./src/output.css --watch",
    "build": "vite build && firebase deploy",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.66",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.22",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.19",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.34.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.6",
    "postcss": "^8.4.38",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.3",
    "vite": "^5.2.0"
  }
}


Solved my own problem, for some reason autosave on VSCode was turned off smh
